# Only increase build number for formal release?

Tags: build-process, versioning

what's your strategy to increase build number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most software has a hierarchy of version numbers:

1. The "marketing" version number (like "Windows 7")
2. The major version number - usually incremented when there's a major new version that breaks some compatibility with a previous version, adds a major new capability, requires purchasing an upgrade, or more.
3. The minor version number - upgraded every time there's a bug-fix or minor feature enhancement that's released to the public
4. The build number - this should be incremented every time any change is made to the program, so that if someone finds a problem in a nightly build or beta-test version, you can identify exactly which version was being tested.  This number is often a revision number directly from your version control system like Subversion, or a timestamp, or something similar that makes it easy for you to roll back the code to that version if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

1. All the dlls must have the same version number for one release.
2. Build number consists of "`MajorVersion.MinorVersion.BuildNumber.Revision`", usually I keep the `Revision Number` to be 0. Only the first 3 numbers are changed.
3. For every nightly build, `BuildNumber` will be incremented automatically. I will manually increase `majorversion` and `minorversion` if the changes are sufficiently big.

Answer (score 0):

Every checkin should be tagged a version, use the subversion current version as the part of the build exe version.

Comment: @Benny: Yes, absolutely. You never know when your refactoring might unintentionally break something.

Comment: @Benny: Yes, as musicfreak said, every check should generate a build, and the build version is derived from the checkin counter.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite reasonable to increase the build number for just every build. This way testers can tell more exactly which build they find a bug in and when it is verified to be fixed.

Comment: And definitely don't get into the situation where you've got two different sets of binaries that claim to be the same version number. If you're looking at file modification times to track down a particular build, you're doing it wrong...

Answer (score 0):

We have a build number that's incremented on every build (formal or otherwise). We use a CruiseControl.NET labeller for this.

We have a version number that's incremented by hand only on formal releases, and we define that centrally in one of the CC.NET scripts, which are held in source control.

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone says, increment the build number for every build. We set the major/minor numbers by hand when we do a branch, a branch is usually done a few weeks before release, then that branch gets regression tested. Builds done on the branch still get incremented though.